# Rate limit on a per-IP basis using ModSecurity

Tags: mod-security

How can I rate limit on a per-IP basis for a ModSecurity (I'm actually using Coraza) rule? For example, for the following rule:

```
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Host "foo.com" "id:5,phase:1"
```

I want to rate limit each src IP matching that rule to 10 requests/s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set Dev on Duty reporting. Ordinarily, I would recommend definitely **not** to attempt to implement any sort of rate limiting logic inside ModSecurity. Indeed, we recently *removed* the rate limiting rules from the ModSecurity Core Rule Set (and into an optional plugin). The performance and reliability is usually poor when implementing such logic inside of ModSecurity.

This sort of rate limiting logic is almost always better performed at a firewall or at/in a proxy (something like HAProxy can do this very efficiently).

On the other hand, you mentioned that you are *actually* using the Coraza WAF engine, and I'm aware that a [rate limiting plugin](https://github.com/vermaShivansh/coraza-ratelimit-plugin) was written for Coraza during this year's (2023) Google Summer of Code. This could be something that you could test to see if it meets your needs.

Comment: Could you go into more detail about the performance issues you encountered? We want to take this into account when using any plugin. Also, what scenarios should we have rate limiting inside a WAF?

Comment: Implementing such logic in ModSecurity, I've encountered issues running at scale and under load. I suspect this is related to multithreading and clashes when ModSecurity tries reading and writing to the underlying database files simultaneously. Strange errors ensue. The performance is also quite poor when handling lots of connections, leading to high usage of the underlying storage mechanism. ModSecurity works great in a stateless way; if you want to add stateful logic then it's best to do it elsewhere. This is my experience with ModSecurity: your mileage with Coraza and its plugins may vary.